# SQL Server add random seconds to date

Tags: sql-server

I have a following insert statement as such:

```
INSERT INTO dt_tbl 
    SELECT id, name, date1
    from #tbl
```

For the `date1` it has just a date; example: `1/12/14`

I like to add a random value for seconds to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Always try to Specify the Column name when using INSERT Statement .

try

```
INSERT INTO dt_tbl(id,name,date)
    SELECT id, name, DATEADD(second,(SELECT RAND(100)),date1)
    from #tbl
```

Comment: This will give the same value for seconds for every row of the table

Comment: How is this new query different at all?, it still gives the same value for every row

Comment: NOT SURE,i didn't test it but i think i'm running the select query that's why it'll give the diff RAND for every row.
please say me the reason, it'll be help for me.@Lamak

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t date = '1/12/14'

select  dateadd(
             second,(rand()*60),
             DATEADD(minute,(rand()*60) ,
             DATEADD(day,(rand()*365),
             DATEADD(year,0,CONVERT(varchar(20),@t,120)))) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DATEADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) with the `ss` option and a random value ([RAND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx)) between 0 and 59.

The implementation should be trivial and is left as an exercise. :-)